# KVM package on CentOS 7 like ProXmoX

Tags: centos, virtual-machine, kvm, proxmox

I've been using ProXmoX for a while as a KVM complete environment, which is based on Debian. Now I've got a server that I need to install KVM but it has to be on CentOS 7, is there any complete package like ProXmoX for CentOS?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is oVirt (upstream) or RHV (supported by Red Hat on RHEL).

Check out ovirt.org for details

Comment: Awesome!! that's what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://www.tecmint.com/install-and-configure-kvm-in-linux/) tuto to install KVM on CentOS 7 :

Check your system’s CPU supports Hardware Virtualization:

```
grep -E '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
```

Install required package:

```
yum install qemu-kvm qemu-img virt-manager libvirt libvirt-python libvirt-client virt-install virt-viewer bridge-utils
```

Install `x-window`:

```
yum install "@X Window System" xorg-x11-xauth xorg-x11-fonts-* xorg-x11-utils -y
```

Enable and start the libvirtd service:

```
systemctl enable libvirtd && systemctl start libvirtd
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in this case I need to do everything manually.
ProXmoX does all the installation (mailserver, webserver, vnc, ssh, ssl, etc.)